# re.compile(r' [Б]$').search(' Б') returns None

Tags: python-2.7

It seems that `re.compile(r' [Б]$').search(' Б')` returns `None` even though it should return `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match=' Б'>`.

This happens when running it on python2, but not on python3, and it happens only with a Unicode symbol (I tried Cyrillic and Chinese). It works fine with Latin symbols.

```
sashoalm@HP:~/$ python2
Python 2.7.17 (default) 
>>> print(re.compile(r' [Б]$').search(' Б'))
None
```

Any idea what is happening? Is it a real bug or is it supposed to fail?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I realized what is happening after reading https://snarky.ca/why-python-3-exists/ - the part about bytes - python is treating the unicode utf8 symbol as 2 ASCII characters - `\xd0\x91`, so it has to match a space, then only one of the 2, then end.

This means that `print(re.compile(r' [Б][Б]$').search(' Б'))` will match.